# Use dlsym on a static binary

Tags: static-linking, dlopen, dlsym

Is there any hope of running `dlopen(NULL, ...)` and getting symbols for a statically compiled binary?

For example, with the following code I can get symbols if the program is compiled dynamically and I use `-rdynamic`.

```
$ gcc -o foo foo.c -ldl -rdynamic
$ ./foo bar
In bar!
```

But with `-static` I get a cryptic error message:

```
$ gcc -static -o foo foo.c -ldl -rdynamic
/tmp/cc5LSrI5.o: In function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x3a): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
$ ./foo bar
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/: cannot read file data: Is a directory
```

The source for `foo.c` follows:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() { printf("In foo!\n"); }
int bar() { printf("In bar!\n"); }

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  void *handle;
  handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
  if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
  }

  typedef void (*function)();
  function f = (function) dlsym(handle, argv[1]);
  if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    return 2;
  }
  f();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any hope of running dlopen(NULL, ...) and getting symbols for a statically compiled binary?

No.

On most UNIXes you can't even link with `-static` and `-ldl` at the same time. Using glibc you can, but the utility of doing so is *very* limited. Basically, this ability is present only to support /etc/nsswitch.conf, and nothing else.

There is also *no point* in doing the dynamic lookup you did.

If you are trying to allow one of `foo`, `bar` or `baz` be called depending on command line arguments, just put a table in, e.g.

```
struct { const char *fname, void (*fn)(void) } table[] =
  { {"foo", &foo}, {"bar", &bar}, ...};

for (int i = 0; i < ...; ++i)
  if (strcmp(argv[1], table[i].fname) == 0)
    // found the entry, call it
    (*table[i].fn)();
```

If you are trying to "maybe" call `foo` if it is linked in, and do nothing otherwise, then use weak references:

```
extern void foo(void) __attribute((weak));

if (&foo != 0) {
  // foo was linked in, call it
  foo();
}
```